# My JavaScript factorial function returns 0 every time

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript. I have written a none recursive function which I want to return the factorial of a given number.

```
function factorialize(n) {
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     n *= i;
  }
  return n;
}

factorialize(5);
```

so result should be `120`

I keep getting `0`

Comment: that's not how a factorial works..... 5*4*3*2*1 = 120

Comment: That's not how factorial works.  `5!` is `5 * 4 * 3 *2 * 1`.

Comment: You are doing `n *= i`, which means `n = n * i;`.  Anything times `0` is `0`.  You need to adjust your `for` loop.

Comment: FYI `(5 * 0) + (5 * 1) + (5 * 2) + (5 * 3) + (5 * 4) + (5 * 5)` is 75.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping from 0 to n ...Multiplyin any number with 0 will be 0
another thing ,you are looping it till n and incrementing with i in every loop ,it goes into infinite loop

change it to the following

```js
function factorialize(n) {
  var length=n;
  if(n==0) return 1;
  for(var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
     n *= i;
  }
  return n;
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You have two (well, three) mistakes in your code:

First `i` must start from `1` (instead of `0`) and go up to `f - 1` otherwise at the first iteration it will be set to `0` (where `f` is the number you need to factorialized - note I changed the argument of the function)

Second, you cannot use `n` for both the upper bound of the `for` loop and the result being calculated. So you need another variable (here's why I added `f`).

```
function factorialize(f) {
  var n = f;
  for(var i = 1; i < f; i++) {
     n *= i;
  }
  return n;
}
```

However here (in my above snippet too) there is a **third** error: because factorial of `0` should be 1 awhile the function will return `n` (the `for` loop is skipped).

As factorial is usually expressed as `1 * 2 * 3 * ... * f` I would rewrite all the above this way:

```
function factorialize(f)
{
    var res,
        i;

    res = 1;

    for( i = 1; i <= f, i++ )
    {
        res *= i;
    }

    return res;
}
```

This last function will give you correct result with `factorialize(0)` too.

Eventually the only remainder is check for negative `f`.

Answer (score 1):

You should start from 1 to n.

```
function factorialize(n) {
  var ret = 1;
  for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     ret *= i;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

In the original code, `i` started from `0`. The result will always be `0` as `0 * (any number)` will result in `0`.

Comment: That's a infinite loop, no?

Comment: this would go into endless infinite loop

Comment: Yes,it's a infinite loop.

Comment: The code updated and it's not infinite loop anymore.

Answer (score 1):

With your code:

- loop1: n = 5 * 0 | n = 0
- loop2: n = 0 * 1 | n = 0
- loop3: n = 0 * 2 | n = 0
- loop4: n = 0 * 3 | n = 0
- loop5: n = 0 * 4 | n = 0

and then you return 0

"**i**" must start from 1, otherwise, in every loop you multiply by 0.

I don't provide a solution, because you have already received a lot of correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
function factorialize(n) {
  var p=1;
  for(var i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
     p*=i;
  }
  return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually doing this

n = (5 * 0 * 1 * 2*  3 * 4 * 5 * 6)